# Pointers and enum in C

Tags: c++, c, enums

I'm trying to rewrite my C++ code to C and got problems with comparising enum by pointers. Please take a look.

Enum:

```
enum state{TITLE,PLAY,LOST}
```

My function looks like that:

```
void ChangeState(int *state, int NewState)
{
state = NewState;

if (state == TITLE)
{
/* something */
}
else if (state == PLAY)
{
/* something2 */
}
else if (state == LOST)
{
/* something3 */
}

}
```

And when I try calling this function by:

```
ChangeState(&state, TITLE)
```

etc. it doesn't work correctly. Also when I put in my code:

```
if (state == TITLE)
{
/* instructions */ 
}
```

What is my mistake? Thanks from advance for your time.

Comment: State is a pointer, so in `state == TITLE` you are comparing TITLE to the address in memory where state is saved. To get the value at the memory address of state use `*state`

Comment: Side note: that problem is exactly the same in C++ as in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer (use `*state`) to read the value it points to

This means your code should change to

```
void ChangeState(int *state, int NewState)
{
    *state = NewState;

    if (*state == TITLE)
    {
        /* something */
    }
    else if (*state == PLAY)
    {
        /* something2 */
    }
    else if (*state == LOST)
    {
        /* something3 */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to simonc answer, you can also change the `if` statements by a `switch`. Given the case (working with enums) is more appropiated.

```
void ChangeState(int *state, int NewState)
{
    *state = NewState;

    switch (*state)
    {
        case TITLE: 
            // ...
            break;
        case PLAY:
            // ...  
            break;
        case LOST:
            // ...  
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did, its change the address of the pointer. What you would like to do is to change the value of the int that stored in that address(where the pointer points).  So to correct the mistake you need to put a * before the pointer name.

Answer (score -3):

Many programmers use prefixes to keep track of the level of indirection.

If you have a pointer-to-state, it should be named `pState`:

```
void ChangeState(int *pState, int NewState)
{
    *pState = NewState;

    // Error:  This changed the POINTER, not the value referenced by the pointer.
    // state = newState; 

    [....]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: My answer is structurally identical to the answer by @simonc:  Basically, OP needs to *dereference* pointers to use them. I also point out it is easy to keep track of the levels of indirection with basic naming convention.   I stand by my answer.